# Rails - Three models joined by a fourth. And Multiple through: associations for same models

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, associations

So my app allows users to guess the personality type of a character. The personality type with the most votes becomes the personality type of the character, and can change based on the votes indefinitely.

So there are four models.
User
Character
Personality
Declaration

(Declaration is the joining table with its model, controller, and views).

Users can cast up to vote for a personality for character, and each character can have up to one vote for a personality from each user.

The data of the personality table do not change, ever.

So you see, there are 4 models involved, where 3 are joined through 1.

This is what I have, omitting the validations.

character.rb

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :declarations
has_many :users, through: :declarations

has_one :personality, through: :declarations # This line is in question below!
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :declarations
has_many :characters, through: :declarations

end
```

personality.rb

```
class Personality
has_many :declarations
end
```

declaration.rb

```
class Declaration < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :users, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :characters, counter_cache: true
belongs_to :personalities, counter_cache: true

validates :user, :character, :personality, presence: true
validates_uniqueness_of :user, :scope => [:character, :personality]
end
```

---

I am wondering which of the following two codes would be valid for properly setting up database associations, and why. I 'll go into my purpose and design right afterwards.

1) character.rb

```
has_many :declarations
has_many :users, through: :declarations
has_one :personality
```

OR

2) character.rb

```
has_many :declarations
has_many :users, through: :declarations
has_one :personality, through: :declarations
```

---

ALSO!, If I have a comments model, where Users has many Characters through comments, and Characters have many Users through comments, Can I just add that in?

Users and Characters already are joined through declarations. Is it valid to join them AGAIN through a second "through:" association?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`has_one :personality, through: :declarations` will not work. As every declaration may have a different `personality`, it is impossible for Rails to decide what to return as *the* `personality`. For this reason, `has_one :trough` only works through another `has_one` or perhaps a `belongs_to` association.

As the personality of a given character can be fully derived from the votes, a fitting approach might be to define it as a computed attribute (that is, a method) instead of as a stored one:

```
class Character < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :declarations

  def personality
    votes_by_personality = declarations.group_by(&:personality).values
    votes_by_personality.max_by(&:size).first
    # You might want to do something different than `first` if multiple
    # personalities have the same number of votes.
  end
end
```

The advantage of this approach is that the value returned by `personality` always reflects the current declarations. Should performance becomes a concern due to the additional queries, you could add a `personality_id` column to the characters table later and update it whenever a new vote is cast; however, this requires additional code to keep the votes and the personality values in sync.

By the way, you don't need `has_many :declarations` in `Personality` and `User` if you don't ever use it as an attribute on that model. (I guess you won't need to query for all votes made for a personality regardless of the character.) Although you most often see the `has_many`/`belongs_to` pair for one-to-many associations, `belongs_to` on its own is just fine.

Comment: excellent stuff. thank you very much.

Personality (at least in my app) has several other non-key info that depend on the personality key.

A given personality has X Y and Z that also do not change. Personality 1 has X1 Y1 Z1. Personality 2 has X2 Y2 Z2. I want to keep from redefining all those methods and attributes, when I use them in other models.

For instance, I want a user to be able to declare his or own personality 

So maybe it's best to have a Personality module to mix in? If so, How does Declaration talk to that module to extract the other information of Personality?